# Create a list utilizing multiplication but not have each list mirror

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, mirroring

Quick question, hope you guys can help:

Here is my code:

```
def nd_mkboard(dims, filler):
     n = len(dims)
     helpboard = [filler]
     helpboard = helpboard * dims[n-1]
     for i in reversed(range(n)):
         if i != 1:
             helpboard = [helpboard] * dims[i-1]
     return helpboard
```

ex.:

```
stuff = nd_mkboard([2, 4, 2], False)
print(stuff)

[[[False, False], [False, False], [False, False], [False, False]], 
[[False, False], [False, False], [False, False], [False, False]]]

stuff[0][0][0] = True
print(stuff)

[[[True, False], [True, False], [True, False], [True, False]],
[[True, False],  [True, False], [True, False], [True, False]]]
```

How do I avoid this linkage problem? All I want is:

```
[[[True, False], [False, False], [False, False], [False, False]], 
[[False, False], [False, False], [False, False], [False, False]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy).

Lists are references. So copying a list is copying references, which means you wind up pointing to the same thing.

Multiplying a list is making multiple copies, as above.

To get around this problem, use the `list[:]` slice notation to clone the list, or structure your code to create new lists each iteration.

You're pretty much doomed as far as making copies goes, since that's what you want to avoid. You could use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy), but you might be better off just writing a recursive function.

**Update:**

Here's a function that recursively builds the structure, and can handle constructed objects as well.

```
def make_structure(dim1, *args, fill=None):
    fill = False if fill is None else fill
    get_fill = lambda: fill() if callable(fill) else fill

    result = []
    for i in range(dim1):
        if len(args):
            result.append(make_structure(*args, fill=fill))
        else:
            result.append(get_fill())

    return result

lines = [2,4,2]

s = make_structure(2,4,2)
print(s)
s[0][0][0] = True
print(s)

class TestObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = id(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)

s = make_structure(2,4,2,fill=TestObj)
print(s)
s[0][2][1] = TestObj()
print(s)
```

**Update 2:**

List instead of args:

```
def make_structure(dims, fill=None):
    fill = False if fill is None else fill
    get_fill = lambda: fill() if callable(fill) else fill

    result = []
    for i in range(dims[0]):
        if len(dims) > 1:
            result.append(make_structure(dims[1:], fill=fill))
        else:
            result.append(get_fill())

    return result
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Any hints for starting the recursive function?

Comment: The function is **recursive**. Greta Garbo was **reclusive.** :-) I've added an update.

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful, thank you so much. One last question, is there anyway to pass a dim as a list instead of multiple arguments? Sorry to bother you. For example, make_structure([2,4,2]) instead of make_structure(2,4,2).

Comment: Sure, just modify it. Instead of dim1 it would be dims[0], and len(dims)-1 instead of len(args).

Comment: You're awesome. You have no idea how immensely you've helped me! Have a great day.