# Create a list by multiplication but not have each list mirror

Tags: python

I have a list:

> newElemLines = [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9','3']]

and I want it to look like this:

> newElemLines2 = [[['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9', '3']], [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9', '3']], [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9', '3']]]

So i thought i can just use this code:

```
newElemLines = [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9','3']]
translQuant = 3
newElemLines = [newElemLines]*(translQuant)
nodeQuant = 11
for i in range(0, len(newElemLines)):
    for j in range(0, len(newElemLines[i])):
        for x in range(0, len(newElemLines[i][j])):
            newElemLines[i][j][x] = int(newElemLines[i][j][x]) + int((i)*nodeQuant)

print(newElemLines)
```

However the original list I multiplicated just mirrors this line for all 4 parts of the list:

```
newElemLines[i][j][x] = int(newElemLines[i][j][x]) + int((i)*nodeQuant)
```

KFL had the same problem:
[Create a list utilizing multiplication but not have each list mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631412/create-a-list-utilizing-multiplication-but-not-have-each-list-mirror) 
so i tried using the solution like this, but its still not working.

```
newElemLines = [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9','3']]
nodeQuant = 11
def make_structure(dims, fill=None):
    fill = False if fill is None else fill
    get_fill = lambda: fill() if callable(fill) else fill
    global result
    result = []
    for i in range(dims[0]):
        if len(dims) > 1:
            result.append(make_structure(dims[1:], fill=fill))
        else:
            result.append(get_fill())

    print(result)



fill = newElemLines  
dims = [3]
make_structure(dims, fill)
newElemLines = result



for i in range(0, len(newElemLines)):
    for j in range(0, len(newElemLines[i])):
        for x in range(0, len(newElemLines[i][j])):
            newElemLines[i][j][x] = int(newElemLines[i][j][x]) + int((i)*nodeQuant)

print(newElemLines)
```

Comment: Don't use list multiplication.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Emphasis on **minimal**. And yes, list multiplication doesn't work the way you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand exactly what you are after, but I assume you want to create a new list of independent elements. The easiest way to achieve that is to use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module:

```
from copy import deepcopy

newElemLines = [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '9','3']]
translQuant = 3

# As for loop:
newElemLines2 = []
for _ in xrange(translQuant):
    newElemLines2.append(deepcopy(newElemLines))

# Or as list comprehension: 
newElemLines2 = [deepcopy(newElemLines) for _ in xrange(translQuant)]
```

Deepcopy ensures that you copy everything, including sub lists, element by element.

Comment: I guess xrange is a typo? It worked perfectly when i used range instead! Thank you very much!

Comment: `xrange` is python 2, in python 3 it is only `range` as you have noted.

Answer (score 0):

Using list multiplication:

```
newElemLines = [['1', '9', '1', '2'], ['2', '9', '2', '3'], ['3', '9', '3', '1'], ['4', '7', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']]

translQuant = 4

final_list = newElemLines*translQuant
```

Using list comprehension:

```
newElemLines = [['1', '9', '1', '2'], ['2', '9', '2', '3'], ['3', '9', '3', '1'], ['4', '7', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']]

translQuant = 4
second_list = [[i] for i in newElemLines]
final_list = [second_list[0] for i in range(translQuant)]
```